# how to do multiple select query

Tags: mysql

```
create table member(
   member_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
   age int(2) default null,
   gender char(1) default null,
   religion_name varchar(30) default null,
   caste_name varchar(30) default null,
   mother_tongue varchar(50) default null,
);
```

I want to select always Female as a gender but all the remaining fields can be correct or incorrect.

It is giving wrong result

```
select * from member 
where gender='F' and age>=10 and age<=30 or religion_name='Hindu' or caste_name='Rajput' or mother_tongue='Hindi';
```

Comment: post the output and define what is wrong

Comment: `AND` is stronger then `OR`, so you simply have to add parenthesis around your `or`ed conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select * from member 
where gender='F' and 
    (
        (age BETWEEN 10 and 30) 
        or religion_name='Hindu' 
        or caste_name='Rajput' 
        or mother_tongue='Hindi'
    );
```